# Python doit: Create subtasks using file generated from previous task

Tags: python, python-3.x, doit

With [Python doit](http://pydoit.org/index.html) I want to generate sub-tasks by reading a list of files from a file (that was generated in an earlier task), then `yield`ing actions for each of those files:

```
def task_generates_list_of_files():

    def generate_file():

        with open('list_of_files.txt', 'w') as fo:

            for x in range(20):
                fo.write(f'thing_{x}.txt\n')

    return {
        'actions': [generate_file],
        'targets': ['list_of_files.txt']
    }

def task_generate_subtasks_using_file():

    with open('list_of_files.txt', 'r') as fo:

        for filename in fo:

            filename = filename.strip()

            yield {
                'name': filename,
                'actions': [f'program_to_run {filename}'],
                'file_dep': ['list_of_files.txt']
            }
```

However, because `list_of_files.txt` doesn't exist when the tasks are being set up by doit, it raises a `FileNotFoundError` exception.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957460/python-doit-use-arguments-in-dependent-tasks) but am not clear that `getargs` can work when generating subtasks, because I wouldn't be able to loop through the list of files until they were injected into a Python action, at which point I can't yield any sub-tasks. Doing that results in:

```
Python Task error:...
It must return:
False for failed task.
True, None, string or dict for successful task
returned <generator object...
```

Comment: The `returned <generator object...` is a major clue. `task_generate_subtasks_using_file()` is what is called a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) since it contains a `yield` statement. The first time it is called it returns an iterable generator object and **its** methods, like `next()` must be used to retrieve generated values. More details can be found in the documentation section titled [**Yield expressions**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr).

Comment: I understand that, but the problem is specific to Python `doit` (http://pydoit.org/index.html) where you can make task functions returning a dictionary with tasks for doit to run, or use `yield` to make "sub-tasks". However I can't open my `list_of_files.txt` in the task definitions that are run when `doit` runs the script, because it doesn't exist until the first task is run. The second part was explaining that I can't use a method to pass values between `doit` tasks (called `getargs`) because I can't `yield` subtasks from a function inside a task (http://pydoit.org/dependencies.html#getargs)

Comment: See [_How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem, then someone may be able to show you how to use `getargs` to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: The example I have given is a complete example. `pip3 install doit`, then place that code in a `dodo.py`, then run `doit` in the folder and it produces the same error. The tags on this don't help because it's not so much a Python question as a `doit` question, and I don't have enough rep to create a new tag. I appreciate what you're saying, and as Python it won't do anything except define two functions, but using `doit` those `task_` functions are run to define tasks, and fail because the second task definition is run before the first task, but depends on output from the first task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I'd missed something I hadn't seen before in the doit documentation: [delayed tasks](http://pydoit.org/task_creation.html#delayed-task-creation). You can use `create_after` to defer creation of a task until after a given task is executed.

In my case this allows `list_of_files.txt` to be generated by `task_generates_list_of_files` before `list_of_files.txt` is read within the task definition of `task_generate_subtasks_using_file`:

```
from doit import create_after

# Show output
DOIT_CONFIG = {
    'verbosity': 2
}

def task_generates_list_of_files():

    def generate_file():

        with open('list_of_files.txt', 'w') as fo:

            for x in range(20):
                fo.write(f'thing_{x}.txt\n')

    return {
        'actions': [generate_file],
        'targets': ['list_of_files.txt']
    }

@create_after('generates_list_of_files')
def task_generate_subtasks_using_file():

    with open('list_of_files.txt', 'r') as fo:

        for filename in fo:

            filename = filename.strip()

            yield {
                'name': filename,
                'actions': [f'echo {filename}'],
                'file_dep': ['list_of_files.txt']
            }
```