# Is there a way to pass command line args for one task to another dependency task?

Tags: doit

Is there a way for the command line arguments given to task B to be used by its dependency task A?

```
def task_A():
    def do_echo_foo_a(task, foo):
        print(f'{task.name}: foo is {foo}')

    return {
        'actions':[do_echo_foo_a],
        'params': [
            {
                'name': 'foo',
                'long': 'foo',
                'type': str,
                'default': None
            }
        ]
    }

def task_B():
    def do_echo_foo_b(task, foo):
        print(f'{task.name}: foo is {foo}')

    return {
        'task_dep': ['A'],
        'actions':[do_echo_foo_b],
        'params': [
            {
                'name': 'foo',
                'long': 'foo',
                'type': str,
                'default': None

            }
        ]
    }
```

I get the following output:

```
> doit B --foo bar
.  A
A: foo is None
.  B
B: foo is bar
```

I expected / hoped that task A would be given the command line args since its param is identically named.

I see that there is a way of getting results from A back to B (as referenced here: [Python doit - Use arguments in dependent tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957460/python-doit-use-arguments-in-dependent-tasks/37683486#37683486)), but that isn't the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: This seems to do what I want, but I think sort of defeats the use of "task_dep" as I understand it:  doit A --foo bar B --foo bar